# Is there a way to add embedded youtube videos to my website sitemap?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap, video, youtube

The goal is to make embedded youtube videos appear in video search results as part of my website.

I searched very extensively how to do this; I found through google some articles that claim that it's possible, but they are old and that method no longer works. Youtube seems to have intentionally changed their website to prevent other people from including their videos in external sitemaps.

To create the sitemap I would need two things:

- The URL of YouTube's flash player. This should be easy enough.
- This is the hard part: the URL of the .flv of the video. For http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE88ZYstEHc it is `http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=cE88ZYstEHc&t=vjVQa1PpcFMQCaCarYkjDrCDJyqOQ_cXrG5ulMRoDY8=` .

The "t" which is the tricky part. How can I obtain it?

Also, am I doing something unethical? If I manage to do this will google and/or youtube be annoyed at me? The YouTube videos are mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Protocol site: **[Sitemap file location](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#location)**:

> Note that this means that all URLs
>   listed in the Sitemap must use the
>   same protocol (http, in this example)
>   and reside on the same host as the
>   Sitemap. For instance, if the Sitemap
>   is located at
>   `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`,
>   it can't include URLs from
>   `http://subdomain.example.com`.
>
> URLs that are not considered valid are
>   dropped from further consideration. It
>   is strongly recommended that you place
>   your Sitemap at the root directory of
>   your web server. For example, if your
>   web server is at example.com, then
>   your Sitemap index file would be at
>   `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`. In
>   certain cases, you may need to produce
>   different Sitemaps for different paths
>   (e.g., if security permissions in your
>   organization compartmentalize write
>   access to different directories).

Also: [**Sitemaps & Cross Submits**](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#sitemaps_cross_submits)

> To submit Sitemaps for multiple hosts
>   from a single host, you need to
>   "prove" ownership of the host(s) for
>   which URLs are being submitted in a
>   Sitemap.

Any YouTube urls you add to your sitemap will be considered invalid.

Comment: Thanks I am also looking for the answer of this question. you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google [Creating a Video Sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80472), you can can also create an [Media RSS (MRSS)](http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss) feed and the cross-domain restriction won't apply. You can submit this MRSS feed to Webmaster Tools, etc.

And I don't think you'll need to grab the FLV of the Youtube video either.